# Using ArcGIS Viewer for Flex

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I need your help on flexviewer,when I want to test the flexviewer I describe the following path: "C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ flexviewer" on my default browser "google chrome" but an error  mssage appears :

"Fault code: InvokeFailed

Fault info: Error # 2148

Fault details: null "

I check the flash player plugin is already enabled for google chrome and I tried to see the solutions on the net without result.

Comment: Are you using the [**ArcGIS Viewer for Flex**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-viewer/) or something else?

Comment: yes, for that I download the file "flexviewer"to test and to know how to change or customize the default ArcGIS Viewer for Flex

Answer (score -1):

have seen this on ESRI forum for ArcGIS viewer for Flex:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24754-Fault-Code-InvokeFailed-Fault-Info-Error-2148-Fault-Details-null

Comment: yes, I solved the problem now I download the latest version of flash player and it works good, thank you :)